# What is the correct way to write this uncertainty?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, measurements, error-analysis

$$ Z = 23,8937 * 10^{-5} [u] $$
$$ u(Z) = 3,721 * 10^{-7} [u] $$

I have to write this uncertainty in complete form. 
Would this be correct?
$$ 0.0002389 \pm  0.0003721 $$

Comment: What's incomplete about the first version?

Comment: My guess it does not answer some standards, since my teacher made this task. It needs to be done as one statement

Comment: Are you using a comma as a decimal point in the first two lines but a period as a decimal point in the third? If so, that’s confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straight forward way it to round the error to the most significant digit, and keep the measured value to the accuracy of the error, thus the value is $0.0002 \pm 0.0004$.

See [Significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)